# How do I get out of a >> prompt in powershell when I made a mistake?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I use powershell with git for the poshgit features and sometimes I'll make an error typing the git command like git commit -m 'something and for get to close the ' before hitting enter. It goes to the new line I type ' and hit enter and I still get the >> prompt. Is there any easy way to say give me back a new prompt and get out of the infinite >> loop with out closing powershell?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 19):

@jon Z 's answer tells you how to abort it, but what you want is to hit enter at the empty `>>` prompt and you will be out:

```
PS > git commit -m 'test
>> '
>>
[temp 7b96875] test
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 c
```

Notice in the last `>>` prompt I just hit enter and it completes the command. This is done when you want the command multiline ( in this case commit message is multiline) and to signify the end, you just hit return on an empty line to get out.

Comment: The question mentions _make an error typing ..._. I believe it's reasonable assumption that the user wants to abort a command containing a typo.

Comment: @jonZ - Yes, I did not question your answer. I was saying, in addition to what you mentioned, if someone wanted to continue the command rather than just abort it, they have to press enter on the last line. Note that OP tried to put the closing `'` on the next line, but was confused on why the `>>` was still coming up. My answer addresses that as well. But your answer of aborting it, should be accepted one and I don't question that.

Comment: Could have swore I tried that before, but just tried it and it worked. Thank you.  Thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Type "exit" at the prompt. ^C didn't work for me. Nor did enter.

Comment: Ctrl-C and Enter didn't work for me either, but this did. Thanks @thund!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to come out of console without running entered command just type Ctr+C.

If you want to run entered command, but power-shell still giving that double right even after after hitting multiple enters, CHECK FOR YOUR COMMAND SYNTAX. 
Possibly any extra WHITE SPACE or QUOTEs might be causing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the various commands in the above answers as well. 
Then I simply "backspaced" and deleted all my commands back to "C:\" !
Works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ctr-C is the only option that worked for me in the similar situation with a >>

Answer (score 1):

just press ctrl-z + return(enter) a few times and you will be out

Answer (score 0):

`Use exit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit`

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to the exit and restart Visual Studio. I tried several of the above first. BTW, I am using VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late on this now, but after having this issue and Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z, Enter, and Exit not working for me, I found this worked:

```
PS C:\Users\[USER]>> $host.EnterNestedPrompt()
PS C:\Users\[USER]>>> exit
PS C:\Users\[USER]>> exit
PS C:\Users\[USER]>
```